# How to convert a rendered HTML to some kind of image file (PDF, JPG, PNG) in Java?

Tags: java, html, pdf, png, jpeg

I have a piece of HTML code that renders a graph essentially, and I want to convert that rendered graph to an image file. I've looked everywhere for solutions but they either do not work (i.e. converts to a blank image) or only works with XHTML files. I'm not sure if its more feasible to store the HTML in a String and work with that, or work with the HTML file itself, or what.

This is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Upside Analysis</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='target' ></div>
        <script>
        var target_target = document.getElementById('target');
        var layout = {
    title: 'Upside Analysis',
    titlefont: {
    family: 'arial',
    size: 24,
    color: 'black'
}
,
    height: 282,
    width: 500,
    xaxis: {
    title: 'Market Rents',
    },



};

var trace0 =
{
x: ['1 Bedroom','2 Bedroom','3 Bedroom'],
y: [2550.0, 3250.0, 4000.0],
orientation: 'v',
type: 'bar',
name: '',
};

        var data = [ trace0];
Plotly.newPlot(target_target, data, layout);    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried putting it through Html2ImageGenerator:

```
String uri = new File("testoutput/output.html").toURI().toString();
HtmlImageGenerator imageGenerator = new HtmlImageGenerator();
imageGenerator.loadUrl(uri);
imageGenerator.getBufferedImage();
imageGenerator.saveAsImage("output.png");
imageGenerator.saveAsHtmlWithMap("hello-world.html", "output.png");
```

All it does is generate a blank .png file, with the mapped .html file blank too. I'm thinking it has something to do with the fact that the HTML file has an imported script.

Comment: Can you please provide some more information on how you actually render the graph? What frameworks do you use?

Comment: The HTML file is opened in the browser.

Comment: I've looked at every single answer on this site and tried like 6 different libraries.

Comment: Check the update